# In R, how to fill gradient color based on median value when plotting boxplot with stat_summary in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot a customized box plot with `ggplot2`:

```
# Function to specify correct box plot parameters:
custom_quantile <- function(x) {
  out <- c(quantile(x, 0.1), quantile(x, 0.25), median(x), quantile(x,0.75), quantile(x, 0.9))
  names(out) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  return(out)
}

# Visualization:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=group, y=value)) +
  stat_summary(aes(y=value), fun.data=custom_quantile, geom="boxplot")
```

I have problem filling the box plot with color based on the median value of each group (x series). I wish it to be a gradient color.

Anyone knows a good way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `scale_color_gradient`? Your likely need to specify column representing `median` in the `aes` argument of `ggplot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` is really good at plotting the data you give it. If you want the fill color to be determined by group medians, give it the group medians.

Using `mtcars` as a demo:

```
library(dplyr)
mt = mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(med_mpg = median(mpg))

ggplot(mt, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill = med_mpg)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = custom_quantile, geom = "boxplot")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful!
So I think the solution is to add another column to the original data with median value of their group.